# What piece of hardware or software on a computer/microcontroller determines what code you can write (and not write)?

Tags: c++, embedded, computer-science

So I am writing code for a microcontroller (using Arduino IDE), which I do not have a ton of experience doing. This question popped into my head when I was wondering which 'parts' of C++ I could use in my code that would flash onto this NRF52840 microcontroller. Basically, I am wondering: What on that board determines the code I must write for it?

I understand saying "what code can I write/not write" is broad, but its because I dont know what to say instead. A few guesses I have for substitutes for this would be: certain libraries? certain coding languages?, certain types of languages (interpreted vs compiled)?

Sorry if this question is too horribly stated to get an answer, but this was legit the best I could do lol.

Comment: For embedded systems it depends on what your OS and compiler supports. Sometimes, IO operations are not supported. Also heap operations will depend on whether the embedded system has a OS that supports it. The c++ language itself knows nothing about this but much of the standard libraries requires OS support. You have to read the documentation.

Comment: Regardless of how you word it it is too broad. Some capabilities of C++ and its library are not suited to either resource constrained or hard real-time systems.  You would use a subset appropriate to your target and application.

Comment: @doug : You don't require any OS to have a heap.  Few parts of the standard library require OS support;  `std::thread` is about all I can think of - and that need not be a full OS, a simple RTOS kernel would suffice.

Comment: @Clifford If you don't have an OS then you need some sort of compiler extension to use the default allocators. You can, of course, build your own heap or custom allocator but that's not part of standard c++. iostreams does what w/o an OS?

Comment: The standard lib for the MCU port will handle the heap. Anyway, you shouldn't be using it still, for a long list of reasons. See [Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286121)

Comment: @doug In every embedded system I have ever worked on using C++, new/delete maps to the C standard library malloc/free.  Similarly iostreams maps to an underlying I/O system if one is provided; often that may be only stdin/stdout/stderr, but may include a filesystem - you don't need an OS for stdio or a filesystem either.  If you do, what have I been doing for the past 32 years?! ;-)

Comment: @Clifford Well then you have an OS. Those are OS services. Most of the embedded systems I worked on used hardware that I designed and had a small assy boot section to initialize a small c core to set up interrupts and whatever was needed to run the c/c++ main code. The containers used pre-allocated ram locations and no i/o. Just monitored ram/rom with a logic analyzer. Had to operate real time because they ran high speed stuff requiring small, consistent, servicing.

Comment: As an aside, the OP uses an Arduino and c/c++ libraries targeting that will provide a large amount of the OS services required for much of the c++ library. What that includes in detail should be documented with the recommended compilers and their accompanying libraries.

Comment: Having services that are often provided by an OS does not mean you have an OS.  For example if I were to use [ELM FatFS](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) and integrate it into stdio by implementing say Newlib syscalls open/close/read/write/seek etc.  I would not claim to have written an OS, merely to have retargetted the C library and used a file system library.  Clearly your definition of an OS is broad and experience of embedded systems rather narrow.  With respect to malloc, again the Newlib sbrk can be implemented to provide memory resource entirely without and OS.

Comment: @Clifford, you are right. I tend to call most everything that isn't part of the generated code, services of an OS. Most of my coding is on a regular workstation. Even most of my embedded coding is written and sim tested there along with SystemC hardware design. Very low level. I need to get out more.

Comment: @doug I think we understand where each is coming from on this now.  Understood.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of using C++, it depends entirely upon what language features the compiler you are using supports. I suppose there might be hardware out there that is so simplistic that certain features are simply beyond the ability to implement, but I cannot tell you either what hardware that is, or what language features would be so effected.

Comment: While the compiler obviously plays a role in it, it's not the whole picture. For instance, your compiler may "support" a certain feature and emit code for it, but it may still fail at runtime. Atomics come to mind for instance: IIRC you have to enable caches on aarch64 for them to work.